# Entity Framework 6 and Unit Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework-6

I have been looking around for a solution but I couldn't find the answer (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132601/unit-test-entity-framework-using-moq) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787968/unit-testing-entity-framework-with-mock-idbset).)

```
public class ItemsRepository {
    public ItemDto Get(int id) {
        using (var db = new ItemContext()) {
            return db.Items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == id)
                .ToDto();
        }
    }
}
```

I used to test this code by going all the way to the DB. I know this is not a good practice, since the unit test in this case tests the connection to the database as well.

Ideally, I want to build an in-memory database and seed it. How would I do that in this case? How do I fake ItemContext to use an in-memory list?

Note that I don't want to expose Context as a constructor, since the user will have to know about how the data is stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot fake `ItemContext` because `new` keyword always creates a new instance of the object. Ideally, you should inject your context by dependency injection. Something like this:

```
public class ItemsRepository {
    public ItemDto Get(int id) {
       return _itemContextService.Items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == id)
                .ToDto();            
    }
}
```

In unit test `_itemContextService` should be injected and `_itemContextService.Items` should be configured with mock data. All logic which you should unit test is:

```
FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == id).ToDto();
```

This is only what `Get(int id)` method does. Connection with database is beyond of scope in unit testing this method.

Anyway, if you cannot use some DI container or somehow inject `ItemContext` then you can mock your connection string in unit test project.